# How Do I Filter My Results Based Off Of Other Entries?

Tags: sql

I have written a statement that retrieves the person name, as well as the food they've eaten.

```
Person | Food Eaten
John   | Cake
Jack   | Ice Cream
Louis  | Hot Dog
John   | Pineapple Pizza
```

Now that I've retrieved what foods people have eaten, I would like to remove anyone who has eaten Pineapple Pizza from my list.

What type of clause would I want to use to create a unique list of people who haven't eaten Pineapple Pizza?

Comment: I would use `not exists` if there is a separate table of people and `group by`/`having` if there is only one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the exact value of the food people have eaten, you can exclude it when you write your WHERE clause.

```
SELECT t.person, t.food_eaten
  FROM eaten_tbl t
 WHERE t.food_eaten <> 'Pineapple Pizza';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from table t1 
                  where t1.person = t.person and t1.food = 'Pineapple Pizza'
                 );
```